# How to create input frame with corners having different size?

Tags: html, css

I design input with CSS. I tried very hard, but I could not get the look in the picture. How can I make the input edges with css as shown in the picture?

```css
body{
 background:black;
}

.form-control{
    background: #0A131B;
    border: 2px solid #08D1FF;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: nebularegular, sans-serif;
}

.form-group label{
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Email address</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

[image: CSS Multi border frame around input element]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiple background can do this. I will consider an extra container to avoid having a very big background definition but it can be done without extra container:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.input {
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent; /*the space for the gradient */
  background:
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top left,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top left,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom left,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom left,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom right,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom right,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top right,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top right;
  background-size:1px 8px,8px 1px; /* 1px = the border width (thickness) | 8px = length*/
  background-origin:border-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.form-control {
  border: 4px solid transparent; /* the space for the gradient + the gap between the box-shadow */
  background: inherit; /* we inherit the same thing */
  background-size:2px 15px,15px 2px;  /* 2px = thickness | 15px = length*/
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #08D1FF inset; /* the inner border created with shadow */
  
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: nebularegular, sans-serif;
}

.form-group label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Email address</label>
  <div class="input">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Without extra container (I don't recommend ...)

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.form-control {
  border: 1px solid transparent; 
  background:
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top left/1px 8px border-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top left/8px 1px border-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom left/1px 8px border-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom left/8px 1px border-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom right/8px 1px border-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom right/1px 8px border-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top right/8px 1px border-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top right/1px 8px border-box,
      /**/
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top left/2px 15px,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top left/15px 2px,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom left/2px 15px,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom left/15px 2px,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom right/15px 2px,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom right/2px 15px,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top right/15px 2px,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top right/2px 15px,
      /**/
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) top/100% 2px content-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) bottom/100% 2px content-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) left/2px 100% content-box,
      linear-gradient(#08D1FF 0 0) right/2px 100% content-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-indent:7px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: nebularegular, sans-serif;
}

.form-group label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Email address</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

---

An optimized version of the first code using CSS variables:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.input {
  --c:#08D1FF; /* color */
  --ot:1px; /* outer border thickness */
  --ol:8px; /* outer border length */
  --it:2px; /* inner border thickness */
  --il:15px; /* inner border length */
  --g:3px;  /* the gap*/
  --b:2px;  /* the inside border*/
  
  --l:linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0);
  display:inline-block;
  padding: var(--ot); 
  background:
      var(--l) 0    0   ,var(--l) 0    0,
      var(--l) 100% 0   ,var(--l) 100% 0,
      var(--l) 0    100%,var(--l) 0    100%,
      var(--l) 100% 100%,var(--l) 100% 100%;
  background-size:var(--ot) var(--ol),var(--ol) var(--ot); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin:5px;
}
.form-control {
  border: calc(var(--g) + var(--it)) solid transparent; 
  background: inherit; 
  background-origin:border-box;
  background-size:var(--it) var(--il),var(--il) var(--it); 
  box-shadow:0 0 0 var(--b) var(--c) inset;
  
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="input" style="--c:red;--g:5px;--il:20px;--ot:2px;--b:4px">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after reviewing your work I had come up with somewhat of a solution.

I think the problem was you didn't have a container wrapper to style around your login.

```
body {
background: black;
}
.container{
border: 2px solid #08D1FF;
padding: 5px 1px;
font-size: 1rem; // 1 rem = 16px
}
form-control{
 background: #0A131B;
 border: 2px solid #08D1FF;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 5px 7px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: nebularegular, sans-serif;
}
.form-group lable{
color: white;
font-size: 13px;
display: block;
margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

you can try this out.  I know you have to play with the container border a little to get the desired effect.  hope this points you in the right direction.